# 404 error in front end and admin of magento after changing store view to a new store

Tags: php, magento

I have 1 website , 2 stores and 2 store views ...ym and main store, I needed the main store view to be the default home page and not the ym store view, while trying to do that in the manage store page, I mistakenly put the ym view that belongs to store 1 under store 2 in the drop down box shown.

Immediately both the front-end and Admin went to error 404 and I can no longer access the website.

please help, I am a new Magento User and I have been working on this website for over 4 weeks and almost done with it.

Comment: You'll need to amend in the database if you can no longer access the admin.

Answer (score 0):

First correct the urls in the database table in core_config_data

Only store view has dropdown menu in the frontend for choice.

When it creates website, shops and views have to share products and categories if necessary, since the pages and blocks you can choose the same for all or will be necessary to have one selected identical to another store

The most common among website and shop is to have a index.php for each, then create a subdomain, copy the index.php and edit the end of it which is the automatic choice of website and shop, then change the urls just that shop for test.

Answer (score 0):

In Database I verified the following 3 tables are consistent
    _magento.core_store_group;
    _magento.core_website;
    _magento.core_store;
Also I changed  in _magento.core_website table the name and code as I had before and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Open index.php and change value of `$mageRunCode='admin'`, then reload admin page .

It will get opened. Go to store view and revert back your changes and select status :"enabled".

Now go back and change value of `$mageRunCode=''`.

Hope this helps.