# Magento - change store view to default via phpmyadmin

Tags: magento

Situation: I have messed up the store view option in Magento admin (very right option in 'Manage Stores'. I tried adding another store view. After saving it, I could neither enter backend nor was the frontend visible anymore (404 error).

I have access to phpmyadmin and was planning to manually change the store view to default again, but did not find the the aproporiate location to do so. Could you guys point me to the right direction please?

(I saw a similar question asked on this board, but with unsatisfying solution: [404 error in front end and admin of magento after changing store view to a new store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674046/404-error-in-front-end-and-admin-of-magento-after-changing-store-view-to-a-new-s))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry about that. However I found the solution myself. However, I provide the solution if that's okay. Somebody else might find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Found this myself though:

- core_store
- core_store_group

Dont forget to delete the cache and sessions or your website wont load properly:

- /var/cache
- /var/sessions